# Heroku app crash h10 error on app's frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, web-applications

It runs fine locally. I've also explored a bit with this problem and installed serve but it still crashes.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "serve -s build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
 }
```

This is the error I'm getting. I don't have have any app.listen on this one too

```
2020-09-05T14:09:25.825345+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-09-05T14:09:25.872402+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-05T14:09:27.642082+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=smart-brainy-app.herokuapp.com request_id=0134fee0-463f-45be-a5d0-06e3e2a5d3d8 fwd="175.176.1.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-05T14:52:43.367119+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-09-05T14:52:54.729639+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-09-05T14:52:57.502907+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-09-05T14:52:57.502923+00:00 app[web.1]: > facerecognition@0.1.0 start /app
2020-09-05T14:52:57.502928+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-09-05T14:52:57.502928+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-05T14:53:00.406353+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.19.58.46/
2020-09-05T14:53:00.406920+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-09-05T14:53:00.407077+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-09-05T14:53:00.407187+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-09-05T14:53:00.407444+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-09-05T14:53:00.407446+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-09-05T14:53:00.505736+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-09-05T14:53:00.561168+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-05T15:18:22.207290+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=smart-brainy-app.herokuapp.com request_id=de13eef1-a1a0-4591-99db-22463fbe251f fwd="175.176.1.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-05T15:18:49.957835+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=smart-brainy-app.herokuapp.com request_id=d88191a0-0044-4bbd-835c-a2eb8ad6d1cd fwd="175.176.1.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-05T15:20:08.380526+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=smart-brainy-app.herokuapp.com request_id=2414e43f-196d-481f-9003-ddf8672d4880 fwd="175.176.1.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I'm pushing through another branch instead of master.